# Can a hyperpolarized neuron fire action potentials?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

Is there any chance that a neuron could fire when hyperpolarized? In that case, would the spike be different than usual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is not what you asked, but there's a phenomenon called **rebound spiking** or **postinhibitory spiking** where a hyperpolarization causes spiking. This is due to the oscillatory property of membrane dynamics (certain subsets of type-II neurons). Spikes can be evoked after inhibitory current stops. Figure 7.29 from Izhikevich's book:

[image]

Here's a partial figure from Hasselmo 2014 (recordings from entorhinal cortex stellate cells).

[image]

References:

- Hasselmo, M. E. (2014). [Neuronal rebound spiking, resonance frequency and theta cycle skipping may contribute to grid cell firing in medial entorhinal cortex](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rstb.2012.0523). Phil. Trans. R. Soc. B, 369(1635):20120523+.
- Izhikevich, E. M. (2007). Dynamical systems in neuroscience : the geometry of excitability and bursting. Computational neuroscience. MIT Press.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, no. An **[action potential](http://webspace.ship.edu/cgboer/actionpot.html)** is initiated due to the activation of Na<sup>+</sup> channels. These are so-called **[voltage-gated channels](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2230911/)**, meaning that they sense a **[depolarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depolarization)** and subsequently open their Na<sup>+</sup> pore to allow Na<sup>+</sup> to flow in, further depolarizing the cell. This is the depolarizing phase of an action potential.

**[Voltage-gated K<sup>+</sup> channels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_potassium_channel)** open up also due to depolarization, but have slower kinetics and hence they kick in later than the Na<sup>+</sup> channels. Influx of K<sup>+</sup> opposes the effect of Na<sup>+</sup> influx and brings the cell membrane potential back to its resting state (or even hyperpolarizes the cell). This ends the action potential (Fig. 1).

[image: AP]
<sup>Fig. 1. Action potential and membrane conductances. source: [Antranik](http://antranik.org/what-is-an-action-potential-nerve-impulse/)</sup>

An action potential cannot be generated in a **[hyperpolarized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperpolarization_(biology))** state, because the Na<sup>+</sup> channels are closed. A depolarization is necessary to open them.

If a neuron was able to fire when hyperpolarized, there would be no regulatory mechanism to inhibit the cell. This would mean it would keep on firing, regardless of its input - not very useful.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lodish , The Action Potential and Conduction of Electric Impulses. In: *Molecular Cell Biology*, 4<sup>th</sup> ed. New York: W. H. Freeman (2000)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21668/)</sub>

Comment: several neurons have been found that _do_ exhibit action potentials when hyper polarized, and my answer highlights several of these regimes.

Answer (score 1):

So far, we're still missing some interesting cases in your answers. Izhikevich has developed a strikingly simple model that covers the following, including several inhibition-induced action potentials, and there are specific cells that have been discovered matching these behaviors:

[image: http://www.izhikevich.org/publications/figure1.gif]

(taken from: http://www.izhikevich.org/publications/whichmod.htm#izhikevich)

Notice:

- M) Rebound spike (as has been mentioned)
- N) Rebound bursting
- O) Threshold variability
- S) Inhibition-induced spiking
- T) Inhibition-induced bursting

Also Noteworthy:

- K) Resonators, if I recall, can be frequency responsive to inhibitory signals
- P) Bistable, again, if I recall, bistable neurons can be switched with inhibitory signals

His textbook *Dynamical Systems in Neuroscience* (and I'm sure several papers, or references) goes through the names of specific cells, for these, such as: Stellate Cells of Entorhinal Cortex exhibit rebound spikes and Spiny Projection Neurons of Neostriatum exhibit bistability.